# sql server thinks empty string equals to some characters

Tags: sql-server, unicode, special-characters, string

`if N'ab' = N'aޢb'
select 'hit'`

this will print 'hit'. 
i dont know why did sql server thinks these two string are equal.
it seems that '�', or 'ޢ' or just empty string, are equal for sql server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character you are using is [TAI LE LETTER SA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1954/index.htm) which is part of a block in Unicode [reserved for annotations](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/thaanachart.html).  They are decorations and not really text, so they can be treated as invisible by SQL Server.

Comment: Is there a list of all these 'invisible' characters treated by sql server??